# Adding our own option to any file like photo, video etc

Tags: blackberry

After you installed the Facebook or twitter, we get an opton "Send to FaceBook" or "Send to Twitter" appearing in RIM's native app camera. For example, if you select a photo in RIM's native Camera app or Media Center app and click Menu key, the "Send to Facebook" is listed. After you click on it, it seems to invoke the installed facebook app and pop up a screen so that you can send the photo to facebook.

My question is, how to add our own option to any file like photo, video etc

Answer (score 0):

Your custom app can add a custom menu item to some native BB apps (e.g. Camera, Calendar, etc).

To start with - check the [documentation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17953/Menu_items_565588_11.jsp) on how to do this. Also check some JDE samples on this (should be present on your PC as a part of BB SDK).